# Why won't HttpResponseRedirect update the URL?

Tags: django, django-views, django-urls

I want an optional slug in my applications's URLs, like how Stack Overflows does its URLs:

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/<question_id>/<question_slug>`,

where `<question_slug>` is optional. That is, if you go to

`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/<question_id>`, you'll be redirected to
`http://stackoverflow.com/questions/<question_id>/<question_slug>`

My urls.py:

```
url(r'^myapp/(?P<thing_id>\d+)/edit_thing/$', views.edit_thing, name='edit-thing'),
url(r'^myapp/(?P<thing_id>\d+)/(?P<thing_slug>[\w-]+)/edit_thing/$', views.edit_thing, name='edit-thing2'),
```

My views.py:

```
def edit_thing(request, thing_id, thing_slug=None):
    thing = get_object_or_404(Thing, pk=thing_id)
    if thing_slug is None:
        thing_slug = thing.slug
        HttpResponseRedirect(reverse('myapp:edit_thing2', kwargs={'thing_id':thing_id, 'thing_slug':thing_slug}))
    # ... continued ...
```

This seems to work, in that going to `myapp/1/` does render the template I want displayed, but the URL in the browser doesn't get updated to `myapp/1/<model-1-slug>`, like I want. What am I missing? Can I not redirect to the same view like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should **return** the response:

```
return HttpResponseRedirect(...)
```

BTW consuder to use the [`redirect()`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/http/shortcuts/#redirect) shortcut which does the same thing but with much less code.